# Matplotlib histogram shifted xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, xticks

For some reason `xticks` on my histogram are shifted:

[image: image link]

Here is the code:

```py
data = list(df['data'].to_numpy())
bin = 40
plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
plt.hist(data, bins=bin, rwidth=0.7, align='mid')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 13000, 1000))
ticks = np.arange(0, 100000, 2500)
plt.xticks(ticks, rotation='-90', ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Im wondering why x ticks are shifted at the very beginning of the xaxis.

Comment: Please post a plot so we can we see what you mean. Also, it's useful to state the version of matplotlib

Comment: @smci there is a link to the image.

Answer (score 1):

When setting `bins=40`, 40 equally sized bins will be created between the lowest and highest data value. In this case, the highest data value seems to be around `90000`, and the lowest about `0`.  Dividing this into 40 regions will result in boundaries with non-rounded values. Therefore, it seems better to explicitly set the bins boundaries to the values you really want, for example dividing the range 0-100000 into 40 (so 41 boundaries).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
data = np.random.lognormal(10, 0.4, 100000)
data[data > 90000] = np.nan
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
for ax in axes:
    if ax == axes[0]:
        bins = 40
        ax.set_title('bins = 40')
    else:
        bins = np.linspace(0, 100000, 41)
        ax.set_title('bins = np.linspace(0, 100000, 41)')
    ax.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
    ax.hist(data, bins=bins, rwidth=0.7, align='mid')
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 13000, 1000))
    xticks = np.arange(0, 100000, 2500)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=-90)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the way bins are constructed.

You have two choices:

1. Set the range for bins directly

   `plt.hist(data, bins=bin, rwidth=0.7, range=(0, 100_000), align='mid')`
2. Set x axis accordingly to the binning:

   `_, bin_edges, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=bin, rwidth=0.7, align='mid')`

   `ticks = bin_edges`

I recommend the 2. option. The histogram will have a more natural scale comparing to the boundaries of bins.